# scipy.stats ImportError: cannot import name 'alexandergovern'

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, importerror, anova

I am trying to apply scipy's [Alexander Govern test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.alexandergovern.html#scipy.stats.alexandergovern):

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats
    
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'Data1.tsv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'Data2.tsv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')

from scipy.stats import alexandergovern
alexandergovernTest = alexandergovern(df1.iloc[2:,:135], df2.iloc[2:,:134])
print(alexandergovernTest)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calculate_onewayANOVA.py", line 41, in <module>
    from scipy.stats import alexandergovern
ImportError: cannot import name 'alexandergovern'
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, `alexandergovern` was added to scipy in release 1.7.0, last year. What version of scipy are you using?

Comment: What does `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)` show?

Comment: `>>> import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`
`1.5.4`

Comment: `pip install scipy==1.7.0 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scipy==1.7.0 (from versions: 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 0.13.3, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 1.0.0b1, 1.0.0rc1, 1.0.0rc2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0rc2, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4)
ERROR:No matching distribution found for scipy==1.7.0`

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  If you don't know, you can run `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: it says, the scipy version is 1.5.4

Comment: Instead of using the Python provided by the operating system, you could try using a third party Python such as [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution).  It is free and widely used. (But I haven't checked the support of Anaconda for older Linux distributions.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Problem is solved by upgrading to python3.8 in Ubuntu 20 and installing scipy==1.7.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is resolved after upgrading to python3.8 in Ubuntu 20 and installing scipy==1.7.3, as indicated by @Nelewout and @WarrenWeckesser